# Incoming Express parameters are not the same as whats passed in

Tags: express, mean

I have a strange issue where I have passed in parameters from a URL, into my Express server,

When I get the req.params.code   &   req.params.mode variables, they are different than what is passed in through the URL.

Allow me to show you...

Here is the Express code:

```
router.get('/verify/:user/:mode/:code', function(req,res){

    console.log("STARTING VERIFICATION");
    var code = req.params.code;
    console.log('code: ' + code);
    var user = req.params.user;
    console.log('user: ' + user);
    var mode = req.params.mode;
    console.log('mode: ' + mode);
    console.log('req.params: ' + JSON.stringify(req.params));

    var regex = new RegExp(["^", req.params.user, "$"].join(""), "i");
    console.log('REGEX: ' + regex);

    var verified = false;

    console.log('req.params: ' + req.params);
    console.log('req.body: ' + req.body);
    console.log("rx: "+ regex);
    console.log('req.params.code: ' + req.params.code);
    console.log('req.params.user: ' + req.params.user);

    etc... etc... etc...
```

Here is the output in the console:

```
STARTING VERIFICATION
code: background-cycler.js
user: admin
mode: js
req.params: {"user":"admin","mode":"js","code":"background-cycler.js"}
REGEX: /^admin$/i
req.params: [object Object]
req.body: [object Object]
rx: /^admin$/i
req.params.code: background-cycler.js
req.params.user: admin
```

Here is the URL that is passed into the browser:

```
https://examplesite.com/verify/admin/sms/9484
```

I want to say that this code worked prior to dusting it off and moving an instance to google's cloud compute...

As you can see, the parameters passed in to the verify, code should be 9484 and mode should be sms.  Instead i'm getting an unintended js filename, and a js mode instead.

UPDATE:  As requested I added this within the Express route function:

```
console.log(req.originalUrl);
```

and I get this result:

```
/verify/admin/js/background-cycler.js
```

I can verify the URL that sent this was:

```
https://examplesite.com/verify/admin/sms/9484
```

Comment: Add this `console.log(req.originalUrl)` at the top of the request handler to see what Express thinks the URL was for this request.

Comment: what do you expect in params?

Comment: I updated the OP to reflect the console output of 'console.log(req.originalUrl)' ... What I expect in the params are what was passed in:
{  user: 'admin' ,  mode : 'sms' ,  code : '9484'  }

Comment: Try visiting `https://examplesite.com/verify/admin/sms/9484` in your browser to verify that it is not a problem with a client side request

Comment: Thats where i make the call, in the browser.

Comment: I also get the same result in different browsers.  Perhaps some express middleware, or body parser im suslecting.. Hmm